# Drawing multiple lines JavaScript - not always working on click every click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Im having issues with this code created. The problem im having is when i click to stop the line from drawing its has a 50% chance it will work first time and that is different for some devices you have to click more than once to stop it from drawing the line and im not 100% sure why.

(Im using 1.12.4 jquery as im adding this into WordPress thats what is runs off)

```js
$(function() {
  var x1 = null,
    y1 = null;
  var offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0;
  
  var moveLineId = "moveLine";

  function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {

    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#demo')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });

    if(id != null) line.attr('id', id);

    return line;
  }

  $('#demo').click(function(event) {
      $(".line").removeAttr('id');
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

      if (x1 == null) {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    .delegate('.line', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      x1 = y1 = null;
      return false;
    });
    

  $('#demo').mousemove(function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;
        
      
      
      if (x1 != null) {
        $("#" + moveLineId).remove();
        createLine(x1, y1, x, y, moveLineId)
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    
});
```

```css
div.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000;
  /* Black fill */
}

#demo {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}

div.transforming-on-corner {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<h3> click two point to draw a line :</h3>
<div id="demo" class="wide">

</div>
```

Comment: it works 100% of times with no errors in my browser

Comment: works for me as well